# How to ensure child and parent processes have different address space when using fork() in QNX

Tags: c, fork, qnx

The question is particulary about QNX and pretty much stated in the title.
I tried logging the variable addresses after modifying them in both processes, assuming copy-on-write doesn't work anymore and they are not identical, so I expected the addresses to be different. But they are the same (virtual addresses, but still).

So how can I check that one process doesn't affect another without printing variables value, maybe there's a simpler solution?

```
int q;
q = 3;
...
if (pid == 0) {
    // in child
    q = 5;
    printf("%d\n", &q);
} else {
    // in parent
    q = 9;
    printf("%d\n", &q);
}
```

Comment: @cdarke: It absolutely can be guaranteed. `fork` fundamentally requires virtual addresses (of existing objects and functions) to be the same in child. Otherwise all data storing pointers to them would be invalidated.

Comment: @R - that's true, I meant subsequent operations after the fork, for example if both called `malloc` or loaded a shared object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The virtual addresses you print will be identical — the child process is an almost exact copy of its parent.  The physical addresses the programs access will be separate as soon as one process tries to modify the data in that page, but that will be completely hidden from the two processes.  That's the beauty of virtual memory.

Note that you're using the wrong format for printing addresses; you should use `%p` and cast the address to `void *`:

```
printf("%p\n", (void *)&q);
```

or use `<inttypes.h>` and `uintptr_t` and `PRIXPTR` (or `PRIdPTR` is you really want the address in decimal rather than hex):

```
printf("0x%" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)&q);
```

Print the numbers too — and do so several times in a loop with sleeps of some sort in them.  You will see that despite the same logical (virtual) address, the physical addresses are different.  You won't be able to find the physical address easily, though.

Answer (score 2):

If you have created a new process, rather than a new thread, then it has its own process address space by definition.

Every process address space will have the same virtual address range - `0x00000000 - 0xffffffff` on a 32-bit machine. Every process will have a virtual address of *n*, what it is used for and whether it maps to anything which physically exists will differ.  Some of that address space will be used by the kernel, some might be shared (see also `man mmap`).

After a `fork()` you should not be surprised if the virtual addresses are identical in both processes (although that cannot be guaranteed for new memory operations after the `fork`) - it does not mean that copy-on-write is not working, that is invisible to normal code.

Pages do not necessarily reside in RAM (physical memory) but can sit in a swap or paging file (terms used vary) until required.  The virtual address refers to a page table that knows where its page really lives.  When copy-on-write kicks in it means a new page is created, it does not mean that the virtual address changes, it will stay the same but in the page table will refer to a different physical location.

Why would you want to know anyway?  That kind of operation is in the domain of the operating system.